# Convert a 9 digit Canadian SIN to an 11 character SIN (adding spaces) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am importing data that is providing a Canadian Sin in 9 digit string and I need to convert it to an 11 digit Sin (adding spaces every three characters).

So the original value of `123456789` becomes `123 456 789`. The 11 digit Sin is how the rest of the database looks up people by Sin.

Trying to find a T-SQL procedure to convert from 9 to 11.

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be `STUFF`

```
select stuff(stuff(123456789,4,0,' ' ),8,0,' ' )
```

So...

```
select stuff(stuff([Sin],4,0,' ' ),8,0,' ' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You  can use [format()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function :

```
select format(123456789, '000 000 000')
```

However, for older version `stuff()` would help :

```
select stuff(stuff(123456789, 4, 0, ' '), 8, 0, ' ')
```

Comment: The Format function may not be best for large sets:  https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: @MJH. . . I would not recommend to do such things in `SQL`, instead i would do at presentation  layer.

Comment: I agree, I was just pointing out a possible issue (although Format is very convenient).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to hack this together:

```
[Sin] = concat(LEFT([Sin],3), ' ', SUBSTRING([Sin], 4, 3), ' ',SUBSTRING([Sin], 7, 3))
```

now **123456789** becomes **123 456 789**

PS: I always check that [Sin]s are valid on import or entry (code)

Comment: Not a bad idea but if there is ever a missing digit you’ll get a NULL result

Comment: In c# using SubString if needed: importSin= string.Concat(importSin.Substring(1, 3), " ", importSin.Substring(3, 3), " ", importSin.Substring(6, 3));